# Sequence with minimum length

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The sequences of values that lie between two thresholds `(73, 82)` should be marked, if the sequence has a minimum length `(12)`.

The function `sequence` is what I'm looking for:

```
df['between']  = df[df['preasure'].between(73, 82)]
df['sequence'] = sequence(df.between, 12)
```

Comment: You should probably want to include some sample data. Also, I would recommend against `df.between` as a way to access the column.

Comment: Have you attempted anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a numpy solution that I am sure can be translated to pandas (as an exercise for the reader).

```
low = 73
high = 82
min_len = 12
```

First mask all the locations:

```
mask = ((x >= low) & (x <= high))
```

Then find where the mask changes sign:

```
swap = np.diff(np.r_[False, mask, False])
```

The extra padding was so that the first and last element are correctly represented. Now convert that to indices:

```
ind = np.flatnonzero(swap)
```

Every even element of `ind` represents the start of a run. Odd elements are the ends. The lengths of the segments are given by

```
start = ind[::2]
end = ind[1::2]
lens = end - start
```

You can select which indices you want to select or drop based on the lengths:

```
lmask = lens >= min_length
```

To make a mask from indices, use `np.cumsum`. Here, we will basically replace the original mask with the thresholded one:

```
result = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=np.int8)
result[start[lmask]] = +1
lmask[-1] = False  # This eliminates the element past the end of the array
result[end[lmask]] = -1
result = np.cumsum(result, out=result).view(bool)
```

**Example**

Here is a small example to show you what is happening at every step

```
low = 3
high = 7
n = 3

np.random.seed(1)
x = np.random.randint(low - 2, high + 2, 20)
# 6, 9, 6, 1, 1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 3, 5, 8, 8, 2, 8, 1
mask = (x >= low) & (x <= high)
# 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1

swap = np.diff(np.r_[False, mask, False])
# 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
ind = np.flatnonzero(swap)
# 0,       3,       6,    8,         12,13,14,   17,   18,   20

start = ind[::2]
# 0, 6, 12, 14, 18
end = ind[1::2]
# 3, 8, 13, 17, 20
lens = end - start
# 3, 2, 1, 3, 2
lmask = lens >= min_length
# 1, 0, 0, 1, 0

result = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=np.int8)
# 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
result[start[lmask]] = +1
# 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
lmask[-1] = False  # This eliminates the element past the end of the array
result[end[lmask]] = -1
# 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0
result = np.cumsum(result, out=result).view(bool)
# 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
```

**TL;DR**

```
def sequence(x, low, high, thresh):
    ind = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[False, ((x >= low) & (x <= high)), False]))
    start = ind[::2]
    end = ind[1::2]
    mask = end - start >= thresh
    result = np.zeros(x.size, dtype=np.int8)
    result[start[mask]] = +1
    mask[-1] = False
    result[end[mask]] = -1
    return np.cumsum(result, out=result).view(bool)
```

Comment: Typo: `result[end[lmask]] = -1` -> `result[end[mask]] = -1`